# PHP form success message using isset($_GET)

Tags: php, forms, message

I'm following a php log in and registration tutorial on youtube which has been very helpful until now.

Part 1 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axE55ZKMso4

part 2 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5A50qmC7wFo (Stuck HERE)

Ive established my form and created some error reports, but the problem comes in when I try to get a successful registration message to appear. The page does not seem to redirect to the specified page and anything under my error post section disappears after registration.

Every other aspect is working except the message, Ive followed him down to the letter, however I implemented my own design. Please help. PS. first time posting here.

Here is my code after all my error post statements.

```
      <?php
      if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
          echo '<font color="#FF0033">Registration Message here</font> ';
      } else {

          if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true)  {
              $register_data = array(
              'username'     => $_POST['username'],
              'password'     => $_POST['password'],
              'first_name'   => $_POST['first_name'],
              'last_name'    => $_POST['last_name'],
              'email'    => $_POST['email']
              );

             register_user($register_data);
             header('Location: register.php?success');
             exit();

            } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
            echo output_errors($errors);
            }
      }
      ?>
```

Everything under this, including the form and other aspects of content exist on landing, but as soon as the registration button is activated, all content under here disappears.

I think there may be a problem with  "header('Location: register.php?success');".

In addition, when I force `../rootfolder/register.php/success` through the local host I get an unstyled page? Like its lost all of the CSS and Javascript ?

Comment: are you sure you want $_GET['success'] to be set and empty?

Comment: `empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true` could be abbreviated to `!empty($_POST) && empty($errors)`

Comment: Did the tutorial told you to use `<font>` because if it did, stop watching it right now.

Comment: haha, no. I know its bad practice, but I'm new to php and not sure how to style the information pulled from the database. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use full paths in the `header('Location: /path/to/register.php?success');` and also put this line before `if(headers_sent($file, $line)) echo('Headers already have been sent from '.$file.' (line '.$line.')');` for debugging

Comment: @ Mike Maynard I  know the tutorial first you are using xampp so if you open it outside of localhost in the directory of xampp then you will not have php running on your server because it is not configured it would be like opening a file by clicking on it files need to be opened from localhost

Comment: @MikeMaynard secondly you can style php by putting it in an alredy existing html element that is pre-styled ex <h1>'<font color="#FF0033"><?php echo $registration message ?></font> (I'm not saying to use font its not a good practice to style in html you css with an id or class) dont send to much from the server side its a wast of data

Comment: @MikeMaynard you wrote "Everything under this, including the form and other aspects of content exist on landing, but as soon as the registration button is activated, all content under here disappears." thats because the else statement

Answer (score 0):

What do you think `exit()` does?

```
header('Location: register.php?success');
```

should redirect your browser to the register.php-script. If it doesn't most likely you have any output before the header-call. The header should be sent before any other output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ive tried removing the exit() to no avail. The weird thing is that in his tutorial he leaves it there and it works ?

Comment: @MikeMaynard you are reloading register.php therefore you do not to remove exit evrothing will be reloaded and work

Answer (score 0):

I am currently following this tutorial, someone posted in the comments of the video to put ob_start(); before include "core/init.php"; and it worked.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include "core/init.php";
```

Comment: I know the tutorial you dont need to start the session to register